# SwingFXUtils.toFXImage is Running Slowly in Jar

Tags: java, performance, javafx

I have a simple Java application built using IntelliJ and Maven that runs the following:

```
File myFile = new File("/Users/jason/Documents/TiffImages/bigTiff.tiff");

BufferedImage image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(myFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    String stacktrace = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);
    System.out.println(stacktrace);
}

System.out.println("getting ready to load image");

Image outImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);

System.out.println("loaded image");

bigImageView.setImage(outImage);
```

When I run the application from IntelliJ using Maven/javafx:run, the above code runs nearly instantaneously. But when I build a Jar and run it from command line, the above code takes more than 10 seconds. I can't seem to figure out why.

The specific line that is taking 10 seconds is the SwingFXUtils.toFXImage line.

Has anyone else experienced such a slow down? I can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: Are you loading an image file that exists inside a jar file? or is it the same one as in line 1?

Comment: It's the same image. Identical code, but the SwingFXUtils.toFXImage runs much slower in the Jar.

Comment: Which system are you on - which JDK/JFX version are you using - how big (bytes and pixel size) is your image - anything special with this tiff? Don't you think it is relevant to provide such kind of information to get a reasonable answer for your question?